# A verb following 'than' without a subject

Tags: verbs

> 'Previous studies have found that children living on farms have a wider range of microbial exposures **than occurs** in the reference groups'

1. Is the verb directly following 'than' without a subject grammatically correct?
2. Are there any words possibly omitted between 'than' and 'occurs'?
3. Is there any other examples of conjunctions after which a subject can be omitted?

Comment: 1. No, a root verb would have to be preceded by an auxiliary verb like *does*. 2. The omitted words understood are "the range of microbial exposures that."'

Comment: No: comparative clauses are finite (tensed) ones. "Occurs in the reference groups" is a comparative clause and hence requires a primary (tensed) verb-form. Yes: like most comparative clauses, it is obligatorily reduced. Here the NP "the range of microbial exposures" is missing, but understood.

Comment: oops, I edited my question a little bit. Thank you for your replies and hope you could help me further.